# How do you handle resources in MATLAB in an exception safe manner? (like "try ... finally")

Tags: matlab, file-io, exception

Since there is no finally clause to the try-catch block in MATLAB, I find myself writing lots of code like the following:

```
fid = fopen(filename);
if fid==-1
    error('Couldn''t open file');
end
try
   line = getl(fid);
catch ME
   fclose(fid);
   rethrow ME;
end
fclose(fid);
```

I find having the fclose function in two places ugly and error prone.

Is there a better way for doing this?

Comment: This is just a minor point, but I would suggest not using the variable name "line" in your code. It could end up causing some confusion since there is already a built-in function called LINE.

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847866/how-can-i-close-files-that-are-left-open-after-an-error

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would suggest checking out [ONCLEANUP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/oncleanup.html) objects. They allow you to automatically run code on exit from a function (more specifically, when the ONCLEANUP object is cleared from memory). [Loren from The MathWorks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113700/loren) discusses this in one of her blog posts [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/03/10/keeping-things-tidy/). If you place your above code in a function, it might look something like this:

```
function data = load_line(filename)
  data = [];
  fid = fopen(filename);
  if fid == -1
      error('Couldn''t open file');
  end
  c = onCleanup(@()fclose(fid));
  data = getl(fid);
end
```

Even if the call to GETL throws an exception, the ONCLEANUP object will still be cleared from memory on return from the function **load_line**, thus ensuring the file gets closed.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. I've done some more reading around the onCleanup and new style classes in Matlab in general, and it seems to me that now with handle classes you can practise proper RAII in Matlab which is great.

Comment: onCleanup was first introduced in MATLAB 7.6 (R2008a).  What do you suggest for people who have to maintain compatibility with older versions (in particular, R2006b)?

Comment: @rob: I would suggest telling users not to let their software get 7 years out of date. ;) The serious answer: since R2006b allows for object-oriented programming, making a class to handle file I/O is the way I'd go, as suggested in [Nzbuu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9024064/52738) and the answers of [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8847866/52738).

Comment: @gnovice Thanks for confirming the other answers should work in R2006b; I wasn't sure if R2006b would support them.  onCleanup is only one of several features I wish I could use, but we have clients who develop safety-critical software and have only qualified specific versions of MATLAB for their toolchains, so unfortunately support for R2006b is a hard requirement in this case. Thanks again :)

Comment: The previous delete function from `onCleanup` (`fclose(fid)`) is also called if the line `c = onCleanup(@()fclose(fid));` is called again, in a loop or so.

Answer (score 7):

My preference is to create a `FileHandle` class with a `delete` method that closes the file when the object goes out of scope. Also gives you the opportunity to do other more natural file handle-y things.

Comment: More explanation in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847866/how-can-i-close-files-that-are-left-open-after-an-error