# MATLAB array of int32 and writing to file

Tags: file, matlab

In the code below I am expecting the file size to be 4096 bytes (4kb) right? But in practice the file size becomes 1024 bytes (1kb)! I don't understand why?

```
fid = fopen('test.test', 'w', 'b');
buff= zeros(1024,1,'int32');
fwrite(fid,buff);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Also, if you are dealing with files, this post might interest you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847866/how-can-i-close-files-that-are-left-open-after-an-error/8847870#8847870

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [FWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fwrite.html), by default, writes data out as `'uint8'` type (i.e. one quarter the size of an `'int32'`). It doesn't automatically detect the type of the data passed to it, so you need to specify the type for the output in the call to FWRITE, like so:

```
fwrite(fid, buff, 'int32');
```