# Error in Matlab: Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:

Tags: java, matlab, runtime-error

I can connect with a sever where there are two versions of matlab Matlab_R2013a,      Matlab_R2012a and another version of Matlab_R2012b in my local ubuntu 12.10 pc. For last few weeks I have been facing a problem. Sometimes I can run the code in my pc but after if it takes long or if I try to run similar code few times I am getting an error and Matlab No longer works. Same thing is happening for the Matlabs in servers also. I have to restart and then again I can run matlab for a short time but after that again I am facing the same problem again and again.

The error Matlab showing is

```
"Caught "std::exception" Exception message is: Message Catalog MATLAB:services was not loaded from the file. Please check file location, format or contents The desktop configuration was not saved successfully

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.workspace.ClassicWhosInformation.<init>(ClassicWhosInformation.java:20) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.workspace.ClassicWhosInformation.getInstance(ClassicWhosInformation.java:38) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.workspace.WhosRecordlistModel.setWhosInformation(WhosRecordlistModel.java:45) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.workspace.MatlabWorkspaceModel.setSuperWhosInformation(MatlabWorkspaceModel.java:519) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.workspace.MatlabWorkspaceModel.access$400(MatlabWorkspaceModel.java:19) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.workspace.MatlabWorkspaceModel$1.run(MatlabWorkspaceModel.java:532) at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libnativei18n.so: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libnativei18n.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.fl.i18n.XMLMessageSystem.<clinit>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.mlservices.scc.SccPrefsPanel.<clinit>(SccPrefsPanel.java:50) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialog.registerPanel(PrefsDialog.java:310) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialogRegistrar.preRegisterPanels(PrefsDialogRegistrar.java:37) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialog.initialize(PrefsDialog.java:95) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialog.access$500(PrefsDialog.java:27) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialog$4.run(PrefsDialog.java:224) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialog.showPrefsDialog(PrefsDialog.java:238) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialog.doShowPrefsDialog(PrefsDialog.java:204) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialog.showPrefsDialog(PrefsDialog.java:121) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsDialog.showLastPrefsDialog(PrefsDialog.java:158) at com.mathworks.mlservices.MLPrefsDialogServices.showLastPrefsDialog(MLPrefsDialogServices.java:45) at com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop$PreferencesAction.actionPerformed(MLDesktop.java:2649) at com.mathworks.mwswing.ChildAction.actionPerformed(ChildAction.java:214) at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.toolstrip.plaf.RegularButtonUI$RegularToolstripButtonListener.mouseReleasedImpl(RegularButtonUI.java:327) at com.mathworks.toolstrip.plaf.RegularButtonUI$RegularToolstripButtonListener.mouseReleased(RegularButtonUI.java:321) at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.mwswing.MJButton.processMouseEvent(MJButton.java:362) at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: IInternalException for "matlab.desktop.currentfolder.lastfolder.ColumnSizes": Cannot open a temp file to save the Settings object. It could due to out of file handle or other reasons. at com.mathworks.services.settings.Setting.nativeSet(Native Method) at com.mathworks.services.settings.Setting.set(Setting.java:900) at com.mathworks.services.settings.Setting.set(Setting.java:758) at com.mathworks.services.settings.Setting.set(Setting.java:700) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.ExplorerTableConfigurationSerializer.saveColumnSizes(ExplorerTableConfigurationSerializer.java:181) at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.ExplorerTableConfigurationSerializer.save(ExplorerTableConfigurationSerializer.java:69) at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableConfiguration$1.propertyChange(GroupingTableConfiguration.java:157) at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source) at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableConfiguration.setColumnSize(GroupingTableConfiguration.java:628) at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableConfiguration.setColumnSize(GroupingTableConfiguration.java:616) at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableConfiguration.setColumnSizeIfNotFixed(GroupingTableConfiguration.java:610) at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTable$27$1.actionPerformed(GroupingTable.java:862) at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/users/ahazra/.matlab/R2013a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:297) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:704) Caught "std::exception" Exception message is: Message Catalog MATLAB:services was not loaded from the file. Please check file location, format or contents"
```

I removed the local .matlab folder. But after that also I am facing this same problem again.

Please help me solve this problem in MATLAB. Thank you in advance.

**Answer**
The problem was basically that too many files were open.

Comment: It sounds like you're opening files without closing them. remember every file open needs to have an associated file close, otherwise you run out of file descriptors

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced a similar problem and, as Petesh suggests, it is a file handle problem - MATLAB can only have so many open files at once. The quick fix is to do `fclose all` in the MATLAB command window. To check how many file handles you have open, use `fopen('all')` which will display a list of active handles. (My version of MATLAB 2013a gets full up at 512 open files).

The key error message to pick out of all the lines of errors it generates is

```
(Too many open files)
```

The better solution is to make sure any scripts you have close files after opening them, especially if, say, you are opening files each time in a loop.

See also: [How to close file handle in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222238/how-to-close-file-handle-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

It must because you open a `.txt` file too many times, but without close them timely.
try this :

```
fidout = fopen([saveLabel_path, 'new_Label.txt'], 'a');
fprintf(fidout, '%s \n', final_label);
fprintf(fidout, '\n');
fclose(fidout);
```

to avoid it still warning you, just add this :
    fclose all;
Be carefull, because you will never see this error again, say goodbye to it forever ...

wish it can help you ...

Answer (score 0):

me too also got the same problem. close the all the opened files inside the loop using fclose() function to throw the error away...
have fun
M.Santhanakumar

Answer (score 0):

According to what files you might have opened and not close, use the $fclose$  function in Matlab (eg. $fclose('myfile')$).
I often use $fclose('all')$ in order to make sure that I don't miss any file :)

Answer (score 0):

if u are getting this error in Matlab, a path is a problem, suppose if u r using any other software like python java,

so u have to do clear the temp file in an environmental variable for example

if u see like `this path in[ C:\Python27\Scripts]` in the environmental variable and go to temp delete this line error will be clear.