# Matlab Java JAR File Handle Locked after Exception

Tags: java, matlab, handle

In Matlab R2018a under Windows 8, after executing a `jar` file throwing exceptions `AddressException`, `MessagingException` (ref. code [ref.1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_inlineimage_in_email.htm)) from the `system()` MATLAB Command, the `jar` file handle got locked.

```
1:java.nio.file.FileSystemException: HelloWorld.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Because the system shell (Command Prompt) call: `[status,result]=system(command)` or `!` has finished its execution, the proper handle is lost (where?) and it is not possible to close it. Note that the `status` and `result` parameters are only the error message and a return int, without any handle reference.

When checking the Associated Handle `HelloWorld` with Windows `resmon.exe`, we got:

```
Matlab.exe | <pid> | File | <path\to\java\file.jar>
```

When triyng to delete `HelloWorld.jar`, we got:

```
File in Use. The action can't be completed because the file is open in MATLAB R2018a.
```

The following approaches do not work:

- Closing File Handles, `fclose('all')`, since no `fopen` command is (directly?) involved ([ref.2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5822-file-handle-release), [ref.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222238/how-to-close-file-handle-in-matlab)),
- Java Garbage Collection `java.lang.System.gc()`, `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().gc`, `clear java`, `clear all` since no Java Object has been created (yet),
- Clearing Java Path `javarmpath('HelloWorld.jar')`, since no Java Path has been added (yet).

How should I release that handle, without closing MATLAB?.

Comment: Restarting MATLAB should fix that. In general, you shouldn't need to run your Java program through `system`, you can load the jar file and run the Java program directly in MATLAB's Java VM.