# try … finally equivalent in Matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you handle resources in MATLAB in an exception safe manner? (like “try … finally”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098149/how-do-you-handle-resources-in-matlab-in-an-exception-safe-manner-like-try)

I use Matlab parallel computing toolbox this way:

```
matlabpool open 

parfor …

matlabpool close
```

If error occurs in `parfor`, the program is terminated, and matlabpool is not closed. When I fix the bug and run it again, `matlabpool open` fails because it is already open. So I need to close it manually, which I always forget. The ideal way would be to change it to (pseudo-code):

```
matlabpool open 
try
  parfor …
finally
  matlabpool close
end
```

Is there any best practice for this?

Comment: I agree; dup. The other was harder to find in search though. I fussed with its title so it'd show up in a search for "matlab finally".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `onCleanup`. It'll let you set up code that'll get executed when you exit the scope, regardless of a normal or a error exit. So it works like finally, plus it quashes exceptions in the cleanup, and all `onCleanup`s are independent.

```
function doSomething
matlabpool open
cleaner = onCleanup(@() matlabpool('close'));
parfor ...
%// and then no need to call close here
```

You need to change the `try...finally` to a function, or stick it inside one, for this to work right. The cleanup code only gets executed with the GC clears the contents of `cleaner`, which happens when its workspace goes out of scope when you leave the function (or when you manually clear it). Unlike some other languages, Matlab's `try` block is not a lexical scope for variables; variables assigned for the first time inside a `try` will stick around until their enclosing function is left. Same for all other blocks: the function is the only level of scoping for local variable lifetimes.

Comment: +1 Because you were faster than me :)

Comment: Note that this only executes when you leave the function, rather than leaving the `try...catch`. In this case, I don't think it matters.

Comment: @Nzbuu: +1 very good point. I've added a note about that to the answer.