# Files created by Matlab cannot be deleted

Tags: matlab, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you handle resources in MATLAB in an exception safe manner? (like “try … finally”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098149/how-do-you-handle-resources-in-matlab-in-an-exception-safe-manner-like-try)
>   [How can I close files that are left open after an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847866/how-can-i-close-files-that-are-left-open-after-an-error)

I create some files and directories via `fopen` and `mkdir`, and I close any open streams with the appropriate `fclose` command when I finish writing to the files. Nevertheless, when I abort a computation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> these directories/files remain in memory somehow and I am unable to delete them. Not even subsequent `close all` calls can free them, I have to exit Matlab to free these files. Any idea how I can counter this behaviour (other than 'stop using abort')?

System is: Win7 64bit, Matlab R2011b.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847866/how-can-i-close-files-that-are-left-open-after-an-error/8847870#8847870

Comment: Thanks, then I guess this can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Another related question: [How do you handle resources in MATLAB in an exception safe manner? (like "try ... finally")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098149/how-do-you-handle-resources-in-matlab-in-an-exception-safe-manner-like-try)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple solution: `fclose('all')`