# Killing a script in the middle of a parfor: how to close open files?

Tags: matlab, parfor

When I interrupt a script in the middle of a parfor, some files are still opened by Matlab (e.g. I cannot delete them). I usually call [`flcose('all')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html) to close all open files but it doesn't seem work in this case. What should I do?

Comment: Since the interrupt signal is an exception (I think), you could catch it with a `try...except` block and use the onCleanup object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098149/how-do-you-handle-resources-in-matlab-in-an-exception-safe-manner-like-try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `parfor` creates a bunch of Matlab slaves who have their own file handles. The two main solutions are:

```
parfor i=1:12 % 12 or some number over your number of workers
   fclose('all')
end
```

or simply closing the parallel pool either using `matlabpool close` or the GUI (bottom left):

[image]

Note that you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find what process is holding a file open in Windows:

[image]

Comment: Note that you can also do `pctRunOnAll fclose all` instead of the `parfor` loop.